# least square approximation: how this matrix calculation equation is deducted?

Tags: matrix, least-squares

I am reading a book "kernel methods for pattern analysis". For the least square approximation, it is to minimise the sum of the square of the discrepancies:

## e=y-Xw

Therefore it is to minimize

## L(w,S)=(y-Xw)'(y-Xw)

Leading to
$$ w=(X'X)^-1 X'y $$

I understand until now.
But how does it leads to this? **What is `a` exactly? Is it constant?**

[image]

Comment: Why the markup for equation doesn't work?

Comment: [so] doesn't support LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would solve for the minima (or maxima) of a quadratic function in only one variable: By solving for the zero in the first derivative:

```
diff((y-Xw)' (y-Xw), w) = 0
```

(only that this "0" is a row vector with as many elements as w.)

after performing the differentiation we get the following. (note that ' is the transpose, not a differentiation operator.)

```
-2y'X + 2w'X'X = 0
```

we transpose the whole expression (so 0 is a column vector) and divide by two:

```
-X'y + X'Xw = 0
```

and finally solve for w:

```
w = (X'X)^-1 X'y
```

Regarding your second question: The alpha is simply the whole expression `X(X'X)^-2X'y`. The point is that `w` can be written as the dot product of `X'` and some vector, which means that `w` is a linear combination of the columns of X' (rows of X).